# Right way to pass a costume class to next view

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

I have read a lot about the patterns of sharing data between views .
I know how to use delegates,and segues to pass data(iOS), but i want to share a more deep question.

Lets say i have some tasks app, and each new task the user create, is an instance of a class called `Task`, that holds all the data on that task(date,text,etc) .
Now when in `viewA`, that shows the tasks list in a table, a user push a button to create a new task, hence has to create an object of `Task` class.
Than i take the user to `viewB` to edit the task, and maybe later to `viewC` .

A few options are possible, but for each i find some inconvenience.

1. `viewA`'s controller is creating the `Task` new object,and pass it to `b`, than b to c, etc.
2. `viewB`'s controller is creating the `Task` new object,than post a delegate to `A`,with `task`

It seems that the right option is 1 , but it has some problems such as that after view controller B edit the task, viewA's controller needs to reload the table with that new task- anyway, than, option 2, posting a delegate from b, seems more simple,so b is creating a `Task` object, than post delegate to the table in `A` to save it and also to reload the table with it .
Here the data is less capsulated .

Maybe i am completely wrong ,but i really try to understand how things should be done right .

Any thought will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could create a data model.

Consider having a TaskManager class that manages the list of tasks, creates them, and knows which one is currently selected (or most newly created).  Either your TaskManager can be a singleton or can be accessed via your app delegate.  Anything that needs to be done with a Task, the TaskManager handles.

That way, you make your view controllers more independent because they don't talk to each other but read and update the current state of the data model from the object that's responsible for it.

Comment: THnaks very much . that taskManager is the Task class that i wrote isn't it? so what else controllers should do? just connect between the the views objects to the data-model , such as pushing a button to create a task ?

Comment: I guess I was assuming that you would have multiple tasks.  If so, then a data model owner that looks after them is a useful 'owner' of the tasks.  For your other question, I'd say yes; controllers are glue between what the user sees or does and the actual program state.